# How to get time value as referenced parameter in C

Tags: c, datetime, time

I am not familiar with C too much, but for a project I have to do something with an API...What I should do is to get the date info of some business entity which is encapsulated in API...

```
time_t _date;
...
..

FieldGetValue(....,&_date);//API's method which you have to give the variable

printf("Date: %s",_date);
```

I am not able to debug because of API's restrictions...I am just writing and deploying and see if it is works...But for this case in printf() line my app. just quits.

What I am asking for is how to get any date/time value from a method as referenced?

Comment: Not sure about your case, but if the API signature expects an address, you the way you are passing it should give a reference the actual object which the API would be able to modify.

Comment: You specify C at least twice, so I'm going to remove C++ tag.

Answer (score 2):

The `printf` statement causes the app to crash, because `_date` is a `time_t` type, not a [C string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string). Take a look at the [`time.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time.h) header functions, where you will find a function to convert a `time_t *` to a `char *` that you can `printf`.